# Twilio call hangs up after hangs up after playing response

Tags: c#, twilio

I am trying to build this simple example using twilio C# api:

```
string accountSid = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
string authToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
    
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
    
var call = CallResource.Create(
  twiml: new Twilio.Types.Twiml("<Response><Say>Ahoy there!</Say></Response>"),
  to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15558675310"),
  from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15552223214")
);
    
Console.WriteLine(call.Sid);
```

This example is from Twilio documentation itself. After replacing the account id, authtoken and phone number, this program just say the response "Ahoy there" and hangs up the call. If I add "Redirect" verb  with a relative or absolute path, it just process the verbs specified in redirected file and ends the call.

I want to keep the call alive and not hang up as twilio api is doing it. Is there any configuration I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

That is the intended behavior. If you want to keep the call "alive", you can add a [`<Pause>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/pause) tag. The `<Pause>` verb waits silently for a specific number of seconds.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>I will pause 10 seconds starting now!</Say>
    <Pause length="10"/>
    <Say>I just paused 10 seconds</Say>
</Response>
```